# One-word equivalent to "show in detail"

Tags: synonyms

> This graph *shows in detail* the relationships between x, y, and z.

I'm limited in word count and this expression costs three words. How can I reduce it to one word?

Comment: I've checked in [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shows+in+details%2Cshows+in+detail&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshows%20in%20details%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshows%20in%20detail%3B%2Cc0), and my suspicions that 'show/s in details' is very rare seem to be confirmed. The phrase 'in detail' is idiomatic for 'revealing all / most / many of the details'.

Comment: This isn't exactly the question, but I think your sentence, any of the following could be used to convey your meaning m: illustrates, explains, illuminates, describes, exposes,  documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use *details* as a verb: "This graph details the relationships between x, y, and z."

> **detail,** *v*
>
> Give full information about:
>   *the report details proposals to improve public transport*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/detail)